# How to curl in parallel from a list of links

Tags: bash, curl, parallel-processing, sh, gnu-parallel

list.txt contains links. I need them to be curled in parallel at the same time. Meaning curling `example.com`, `abc.com` and `123.com` at the same time.

### What I've tried

```
mycurl() {
curl $1
}
seq 1 | parallel -j0 mycurl list.txt >> output.txt
#I've also tried
seq 1 | parallel -j0 mycurl ::: list.txt >> output.txt
#I"ve also tried
parallel -a list.txt mycurl >> output.txt
```

They all output parallel --help

## list.txt contents

```
example.com
abc.com
def.com
```

Comment: `parallel -a list.txt curl > output.txt`

Comment: ```list.txt``` is an argument and a file at the same time, the function has to be included too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see the point of your `mycurl()` function, but you can use it like this if you want to:

```
# Declare 'mycurl()' function
mycurl() {
   # list.txt can be accessed in here if you want
   curl $1
}

# Make 'mycurl()' function available to processes started by 'parallel'
export -f mycurl

# Call 'mycurl()' once with each line of 'list.txt' as parameter
parallel -a list.txt mycurl {} > output.txt
```

Comment: Its downsized to prevent complications.